# Spacing issues with T1 libertine and listings

Tags: listings, kerning, libertine

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{listings}


\lstset{
  columns=[l]flexible,
  breaklines,
  % fontadjust,
  keepspaces,
  basicstyle={\sffamily}, % \ttfamily
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
bla(M) = f(Q, C)
{P}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I get the horribly spaced

[image: bad]

By commenting `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` the second line is fixed (the brackets are different)

[image: second ok]

Or, I can fix the kerning manually abusing the `literate` option

```
\begin{lstlisting}[
  literate={
    {Q}{{\kern -.25ex Q\kern .25ex}}1
    {M}{{\kern -.2ex M\kern .2ex}}1
    {C}{{\kern -.2ex C\kern .2ex}}1
    {\}}{{\kern .4ex\}}}1
    {\{}{{\{\kern -.4ex}}1
}]
bla(M) = f(Q, C)
{P}
\end{lstlisting}
```

obtaining

[image: hack]

How can I properly fix the kerning once for all?
Where's the miscommunication between the packages happening?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with `fontenc` or the `T1` encoding. It is a problem in the font. The reason not loading `T1` appears to avoid the issue is that LaTeX falls back to using Computer Modern for the curly brackets in that case. This is because, when `T1` is loaded, it uses curly brackets from the active T1-encoded font. When `OT1` is active, it takes curly brackets from the active OMS-encoded font, because OT1 doesn't provide them. But the only OMS-encoded font it has available is Computer Modern, the fallback option. So it uses those and the problem doesn't manifest.

Comment: The proper fix for this is to fix the fonts. However, I'm not sure how much luck you'll have with that since I seem to remember that `libertine` is now only being actively developed for OTF support (i.e. Xe/LuaLaTeX which can use opentype directly). So I'm not sure any bug fix will make it into `libertine` support for the fonts you are using.... [But I'm not sure about any of this so it is worth asking - I might be misremembering altogether.]

Comment: @cfr thanks for looking into this. Re the brackets I suspected as much. Libertine is such a promising font, it's a pity it is not as refined as could be when using it with `pdflatex`...

Comment: @cfr btw any clue on what a fix on the font would look like? Is it something that can be done in `libertine.sty` or the font definitions themselves?

Comment: Well, it ought to be corrected in the fonts themselves. It could be done in generating the TeX Font Metric files (`.tfm`s) for TeX. That is, by default, the `.tfm` generation usually takes kerning information etc. from the `.afm` for the font. But you can change it when creating the `.tfm`s. But either the kerning is wrong or the width of the character is wrong in the original font, I assume. For type1, this is in the `.afm` file. (Although the `.tfm` may be generated directly in this case since I think the type1 are conversions anyway. So the `.otf` or whatever should be corrected.)

Comment: Right now, I see the same issue if I compile with XeLaTeX (thus using the opentype fonts) so the bug is not in the conversions to type1.

Comment: In my opinion, the problem is in the listings package. Try \{P\} (P) not in a listing environment; the spacing is good. Try other fonts, such as cabin; the spacing is bad in the listing environment. It seems listings is tailored to specific CM fonts.

Answer (score 4):

Use another setting for columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{listings}


\lstset{
  columns=[l]flexible,
  breaklines,
  % fontadjust,
  keepspaces,
  basicstyle={\sffamily}, % \ttfamily
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
bla(M) = f(Q, C)
{P}    = f
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{columns=fullflexible}
\begin{lstlisting}
bla(M) = f(Q, C)
{P}    = f
\end{lstlisting}


\lstset{columns=spaceflexible}
\begin{lstlisting}
bla(M) = f(Q, C)
{P}    = f
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{columns=fixed}
\begin{lstlisting}
bla(M) = f(Q, C)
{P}    = f
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The placement of `Q` is still unsatisfactory but I guess that's because of the font's design.
But what if I really want the `flexible` spacing?

Comment: Well if you *really* want the flexible spacing, then you shouldn't complain about the space after the brace. From the documentation "The
normal flexible format will insert make-up space to fix the alignment at spaces,". Beside this: listings should show code in a sensible way. They are not showcases for beautiful (math) typography.

Comment: Showing code in a *readable* way is what I am trying to do. This spacing is disrupting readability. The fixed spacing is also showing that listing seems somewhat tailored to some fonts and not others. If there is a way to solve that it may even contribute to the development of the package. I don't see why my question is not reasonable.

Comment: And I didn't mean to "complain": I think the `listings` package is incredibly nice. I am just trying to solve a problem.

Comment: I'm not saying that you are complaining about listings but about the spacing from the columns options. flexible is a compromise between spacing and alignment. It can't by design give a perfect spacing. Its drawbacks are not so obvious with some fonts than others but this depends on the fonts (e.g. the natural width of braces compared to other symbols). If you don't like this compromise use another columns settings.

Comment: Right now I am settling for a different font. The reason I am asking is that 1) listings is very close to give me a nice result maybe there was some way to fix it 2) I guess listings has some kerning settings internally I was hoping one could tap into them

Comment: Why don't you use `columns=fullflexible` or `=space-flexible`?

Comment: because I need some alignment to be preserved, e.g. `bla(M) = X` and on next line `{P}    = Y` the `=` should be aligned

Comment: @Bordaigorl Then you can use a monospaced font, which, IMO, looks much better than the default spacing of `listings`.

Comment: I edited the answer to show that spaceflexible has actually a better alignment than flexible.